# ajaxSubmit does not reload page after first request (in CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, jquery

I'm creating a CMS which has a page edit section.  I'm trying to create a Preview function.  It works fine on the first attempt, but if you then change some text and preview again, the preview is the old version.  It also appears very quickly.  It's as if the ajaxSubmit function doesn't bother reloading the page.

I tried to get round this by changing the url each time (by adding on a timestamp to the end), but this made no difference.  I'm using jquery, cakePHP and fck editor.

Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#page_modal').jqm();
$('#preview_btn').click(function(e){
  // Get current page content from fck iframe
  var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('PageContent');
  var newcontent = oEditor.GetData();
  $('#PageContent').html(newcontent);

  // Submit form via Ajax
  var d=new Date();
  var t=d.getTime();
  var thisurl = '/admin/pages/preview/' + t.toString();

  $('#ajaxForm').ajaxSubmit({
   url: thisurl,
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){                      
    alert(textStatus);
   },
   success: function(responseText){
    $('#page_modal').jqmShow().find('#page_modal_content').html(responseText);
   }
  });
  e.preventDefault(); 
 });
</script>
```

As I said, it works fine first time, but then on subsequent calls the content is not updated.  Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Is it happening in all browsers ? If it is IE related, plz check this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313607/ie-browser-caching-and-the-jquery-form-plugin[/link]

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've tried it in Firefox, which is where the problem was happening.  I'll have to set it all up again to check other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try marking the view (/admin/pages/preview) with no cache. In the actual view put:

```
<cake:nocache>

 // your view content here

</cake:nocache>
```

It may be that the view is being cached by cake so it does not update with subsequent calls.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/347/Marking-Non-Cached-Content-in-Views